# Confusion about linked list traversal and debugging

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was practicing linked lists and I'm unsure about what is going wrong here.

In the first implementation I made a ListNode* result and gave it any value and when instead of returning the dummyhead, I returned dummyhead->next (`resultHead->next`).

This works as expected.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
```

Code:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* result = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* resultHead = result;
    int carry(0);
    while(l1 || l2 || carry) {
        int val1 = l1 ? l1->val : 0;
        int val2 = l2 ? l2-> val : 0;

        int sum(val1 + val2 + carry);
        carry = sum/10;

        ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        result->next = l3;
        result = result->next;

        if(l1) l1 = l1->next;
        if(l2) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return resultHead->next;
}
```

Now I thought maybe I could avoid this if I initially gave it a `nullptr` have a check for null and assign it the new node, and continue as before, but in this case, following the debugger, the list starts losing elements, when I do `result = result->next`.

Code:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* result = NULL; // also tried nullptr
    ListNode* resultHead = result;
    int carry(0);
    while(l1 || l2 || carry) {
        int val1 = l1 ? l1->val : 0;
        int val2 = l2 ? l2-> val : 0;

        int sum(val1 + val2 + carry);
        carry = sum/10;

        ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        if(!result) result = l3;
        else {
            result->next = l3;
            result = result->next;
        }

        if(l1) l1 = l1->next;
        if(l2) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return resultHead;
}
```

> One issue I see is that the resultHead is not getting updated, which
>   is something to deal with I guess (update the condition in the if
>   block)

, but why does the list not get made properly doing it this way?
What is the reason behind it?

edit:

```
Input lists
l1: [2,4,3]
l2: [5,6,4]
It assigns 7 to "result" in first pass
In second pass the list becomes [7,0] at the `result->next = l3` step in the else block but at the result = result->next the list becomes [0];
```

> The issue was only not updating `resultHead` (which I knew how to fix and needed fixing, but I thought I should check if the list is being made fine otherwise) while following the
>   linkedlist it only points to one element at a time, and that threw me
>   off (first time debugging a linked list), the value at that point being 0 coincidentally led me to
>   incorrectly believe the list was being null, but that was not the
>   case.
>
> > Edit: My issue was also not being familiar with debugging linked lists, it's supposed to show only elements ahead as we move forward.

Comment: you never update `resultHead` in your second example. You merely assign the value of `result` to it (which is `nullptr`), and then return `resultHead` at the end, and it will still have `nullptr` in it, no matter what you do to `result`. I think you're confusing value and reference semantics.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but that is not the issue I'm facing, the list is not being made properly either, it loses elements after second iteration, when it starts going in the else block.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your code leaks. When you return `resultHead->next`, what happens to the `resultHead` node? You've lost the pointer to it.  The technique of using an extra sacrificial list cell to hold the head pointer is sometimes used in Lisp, but Lisps have garbage collection.

Comment: @Kaz that is why I was trying the second implementation, but that one is not working at all, let me add the debugger results in the post. I know I could make a garbage node assign it head, make head to head->next and delete garbage, but I was trying to skip it

Comment: Agreed with @formerlyknownas_463035818 , please post a complete reproducible example, with example input.

Comment: Yes I'm reading that post he linked, I'm new so don't know everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what your first code does:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* result = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode* resultHead = result;
    while(l1 || l2 ) {

        ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(0);
        result->next = l3;
        result = result->next;

        if(l1) l1 = l1->next;
        if(l2) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return resultHead->next;
}
```

At the beginning there is a single node say n0 (`result` and `resultHead` pointing to it). And at each turn in the loop you are adding a new node behind result, thus n0->n1, then n0->n1->n2, etc. And the end you are returning n1, thus the list n1->n2->...

In the second case:

```
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* result = NULL; // also tried nullptr
    ListNode* resultHead = result;
    while(l1 || l2 || carry) {

        ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(0);
        if(!result) result = l3;
        else {
            result->next = l3;
            result = result->next;
        }

        if(l1) l1 = l1->next;
        if(l2) l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return resultHead;
}
```

At the beginning you have `result` and `resultHead` equals to null. Thus whatever is happening in the loop (which does nothing with resultHead) you are just returning `resultHead` which is null. You can just modify the positive case of the internal if:

```
if(!result) {
    result = l3;
    resultHead = result;
}
```

thus at the end, `resultHead` will equals to the very first created node.

Comment: Yes thank you for making the code more focused and removing the clutter, but the issue is not just that, the issue is the list is not getting made when I follow it in the debugger, it becomes [0] in the second iteration of the while loop when it goes to the else block for the first time at the `result = result->next` step

Comment: You have to think about what `result` points to: it always points to the last element of the list... This is why you can't see a list through it. Only `resultHead` points to the full list (its first element).

Comment: Okay, yes when I fixed the issue, it return the correct value, I'm new to debugging, this was stupid!